# How do I parse an ISO 8601 date into a Mule flow variable?

Tags: simpledateformat, iso8601, mule-el

I have an ISO 8601 date as a string and I need to parse it into a date and store it as a Mule flow variable. An example of the string is **2016-08-01T15:03:00.043-04:00** and I have tried various format strings using **DateUtils.getDateFromString** and **SimpleDateFormat**, but have not been successful. This is the CE version of Mule so Dateweave/Datamapper are out of the question.

Can anyone suggest how I can parse this date?

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using below command:

## [dateString = new Date().toString();

payload = new org.mule.el.datetime.DateTime(dateString, 'yyyy MM dd');]

Reference URL:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-expression-language-date-and-time-functions